# Print only once in for loop if cannot find an ID

Tags: java, arrays, intellij-idea

I was able to print a message if a student ID is available, but I want to only print a `println` once if the ID was not found.

below is my code for removing a student

```
public void removeStudent(int studentId) {

   for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
       if (students.get(i).getId() != studentId) {
                continue;
       }
       System.out.println("Deleted a profile containing information for ID#: " + studentId + ".");
       this.students.remove(i);
       students = new ArrayList<>();
       return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Simplest solition: Create a local bolean variable `boolean entryDeleted = false` that you initialize to false, set it to true when you remove a student and then after the loop has run use that boolean value to determine wether to print your message that nothing was deleted or not.

Comment: Add a `println` after the `for` cycle.

Comment: What you are getting now? This code doesn't print anything if ID is not found.

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Can you please not use the [intellij-idea] tag unless your question is specifically about Intellij.  This question is nothing to do with your IDE.  Mistagging question will cause people who use tags correctly when search and filtering to waste their time on questions that are not relevant to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you not use any method in java.util.List ?
I mean, if I have to write a method who delete one (or duplicate) id and print something I would write something like this

```
    public void removeStudent(int studentId) {
        if( students.contains(studentId)) {
            students.removeIf(id -> id==studentId);
            System.out.println("Deleted a profile containing information for ID#: " + studentId + ".");
            }
        else 
            System.out.println("nothing to delete");
    }
```

But if you don't want to change your code to much you can just do something like this

```
public void removeStudent(int studentId) {

   for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
       if (students.get(i).getId() != studentId) {
                continue;
       }
       System.out.println("Deleted a profile containing information for ID#: " + studentId + ".");
       this.students.remove(i);
       students = new ArrayList<>();
       return;
  }
  System.out.println(" Id not found ");
}
```

And I'm pretty sure stream can make this job smoother than those 2 snippet

BR

Comment: in the first snippet you use the `students.contains(studentId)`, which is always `false`, due to the fact thar `List<Student>` can not contain `int` value

Comment: in the second snippet the `return;` statement makes exit after the first match even if several students with specified ids could be found.

Comment: ahh programming. i love it and hate it at the same time

Comment: @JoseBeltran how could it work if it has critical errors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on answer of Tim, I'd recommend remove the `break` to delete all students with the same id, but print only once:

```java
public boolean removeStudent(int studentId) {
    boolean removed = false;
    for (int i=0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        if (students.get(i).getId() == studentId) {
            System.out.println("Deleted a profile containing information for ID#: " + studentId + ".");
            this.students.remove(i);
            removed = true;
        }
    }

    return removed;
}
```